# OneNote Drawing problems

Tags: microsoft-onenote, drawing

I'm using OneNote and used the pen tool then but when I change sections, my drawing carried over, like the drawing exists in a layer above the notebook and I can't use the eraser tool:

[image]

[image]

I used the pen in the 1st section, but then shows up in the other section.

Comment: What else can you say about the problem? Is it only these pages and sections? Is it carrying over between notebooks? Does it persist even after restarting OneNote? Is it possible you've somehow added that drawing to the page template?